# C++ inheritance and polymprphism, very interesting

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, polymorphism, multiple-inheritance

ok guys,
here is a very strange result i get when i try the code below.
i tried it with two compilers, cl from visual studio, and gcc on onlinegdb.com
the result is the same, so the error is reproducible , but the result itself is not obvious to figure out by hand.
check the comments in the code to know what i think it is supposed to happen.

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    class base
    {
     public:
          virtual void f() { cout << "in base::f()\n"; };
          virtual void g() { cout << "in base::g()\n"; };
          virtual ~base()  { cout << "base::~base()\n";};
    };

    class derived1 : public virtual base
    {
     public:
         derived1() { cout<<"dervied1 constructed\n"; };
         void f()   { cout << "in derived1::f()\n"  ; };
         ~derived1(){ cout << "derived1::~derived1()\n";};
    };

    class derived2 : public virtual base
    {
     public:
         derived2(base* b, derived1* d1)
         {
          cout<<"derived2 constructed\n";
          b->f();  
          d1->g();
         };

         void g() 
         {
          cout << "in dervied2::g()\n";
         };

         ~derived2()
         { 
          cout << "derived2::~derived2()\n";};
         };

    class C : public derived1, public derived2
    {
     public:
          C() : derived2 (this, this) {};

          void f() 
          { 
           cout << "in C::f()\n"; 
          };

          ~C() 
          { 
           cout << "C::~C()\n"; 
          };
    };

    int main()
    {
     derived1 d1;

     derived2 d2(&d1, &d1 ); // TAG 1

     base* c_as_b = new C;   //   TAG 2

     derived2* d2_as_c = new C; // same as TAG 2

     c_as_b->f();            // TAG 3
     d2_as_c->f();           // TAG 4

     delete d2_as_c;
     delete c_as_b;

     return 0;
    }
```

## CODE OUTPUT:

```
dervied1 constructed <- result of: derived1 d1;                                                                                                  
derived2 constructed -|
in derived1::f()      | result of: derived2(&d1,&d1); // TAG 1
in base::g()         _|
dervied1 constructed -
derived2 constructed  |
in base::f()          | result of: base* b_as_c = new C; // TAG 2
in dervied2::g()     _|
dervied1 constructed -
derived2 constructed  |
in base::f()          | same as the above.
in dervied2::g()     _|
in C::f()
in C::f()
C::~C()
derived2::~derived2()
derived1::~derived1()
base::~base()
C::~C()
derived2::~derived2()
derived1::~derived1()
base::~base()
derived2::~derived2()
base::~base()
derived1::~derived1()
base::~base()
```

**TAG 1:**
has a correct output, following the rule of accessing a derived class through a pointer to the base class.

**TAG 2:**
for my understanding, at class C construction, derived1 and derived2 are constructed first, which means class C contains a pointer to a vtable where derived1::f() overrides base::f(), and derived2::g() overrides base::g(), so at this moment in time of construction of class C, C::f() points to derived1::f() and C::g() points to derived2::g().....but it looks like there is only a pointer to the vtable of the last class constructed which is derived2, where derived2::g() overrides base::g(), and there is no override for base::f(). [try to inverse the order of the two base classes for class C]

this is an obscure corner case for me, but it looks like all the compilers agree on the result!

Can anyone explain what's going on here?

Comment: Can you post the output? And improve the indentation?

Comment: There are plenty of questions discussing what happens when virtual method called from constructor... Make sure to check them out and than update your question with true [MCVE] and reasoning why you believe you should get behavior you would like.

Comment: @NickyC : i did rewrote the post with improved indentation and an output of the code as i got it from the two compilers

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov : i read documentations about this, but none explain this corner case, i read also ISO C++ documentation but its complicated jargon makes it impractical to get quick answer, but eventual if i don't find an answer here i will visit it again.

Comment: *interesting* would not be the word I used to describe virtual inheritance, multiple inheritance and the diamond problem. I would say nothing less of a  *headache*.